# Using HTML special characters code vs pasting the special codes directly

Tags: html, parsing, character-encoding, ascii, markup

Which is considered a better practice and why in terms of what does it effect:

To use special characters HTML codes in a webpage for example `&copy;` for copyright or to use `Character Map` and copy paste the symbol in the page directly.

To be more specific under which circumstances is it **NOT** recommended to use html literals?

Comment: There are named character entity references and numeric character entity references. All characters are Unicode, regardless of the document encoding. If using any of the Unicode encodings for the document character encoding, you never need to use a character entity reference. For encodings of other character sets, if a character cannot be represented naturally, you must use a character entity reference and there are only so many named character entity references defined. Is your question specifically about them?

Comment: IMO, it&apos;s silly to use `&apos;` where you could use `'` but that might an exception to the rule you are considering.

Comment: I saw some coding trainers, suggest that it is best practice to use, copy and paste from character map directly in HTML code, without explaining why.

Answer (score 6):

Literal characters:

- Use fewer bytes
- Are generally easier to read in source code
- Can be easier to type if you know how to produce them on your keyboard

Entities:

- Can be less ambiguous in source code
- Can be typed on any keyboard
- Work even if your somehow manage to screw up the encoding of the document

Which is "better" depends on the particular circumstances.